# OCaml: Currying without defined values

Tags: function, ocaml, return, currying

I have two functions f and g and I am trying to `return f(g(x))` but I do not know the value of x and I am not really sure how to go about this.

A more concrete example: if I have functions `f = x + 1` and `g = x * 2` and I am trying to `return f(g(x))` I should get a function equal to `(x*2) + 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have it right, `f(g(x))` should work fine. I'm not sure why you have a `return` keyword there (it's not a keyword in ocaml). Here is a correct version,

```
let compose f g x = f (g x)
```

The type definition for this is,

```
val compose : ('b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'c = <fun>
```

Each, 'a,'b,'c are abstract types; we don't care what they are, they just need to be consistent in the definition (so, the domain of `g` must be in the range of `f`).

```
let x_plus_x_plus_1 = compose (fun x -> x + 1) (fun x -> x * 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much that helped a lot! But I have another question, how is it that we are allowed to call compose without specifying a value for x?

Comment: Function returns function. HOF!

Comment: Perhaps what is happening is clearer when writing it `let compose f g = fun x -> f (g x)` but these programs are exactly the same thing (one is syntactic sugar for the other, I am not sure which). Calling `compose f g` doesn't require a value for `x` because `compose f g` doesn't use `x`: it builds and returns a function.

Comment: @nicotine; Yes, it returns a functions that takes the newly defined types. In fact, this is the point of currying. So, for example, x_plus_x_plus_1 is a function of, (int -> int).